# Select rows with "ONLY" a condition

Tags: sql, join, select, teradata

I've just started learning SQL, and i'm using [teradata](http://tunweb.teradata.ws/trial/) trial database to practice ( using the **db_pvfc9_std** database after you click "Execute Trial" ). [Here is a link](https://docdro.id/YkssaJO) to a document with the database schema.

I have a couple of queries with a **only** clause, e.g:

*QUERY: What are the names of employees who can only use 12in BandSaw?*

so, this is what i have so far:

```
SELECT Employee_Name
FROM   EMPLOYEE_T as ETT, EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_T as EST, SKILL_T as ST
WHERE  ETT.Employee_ID = EST.Employee_ID and EST.Skill_ID = ST.Skill_ID and ST.Skill_Description = 
'12in Band Saw'
```

i think i'm getting employees who can use 12in band saw, but i don't know how to implement the 'only' part, where i wont get those who can also use other kinds.. can someone explain?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Simple do not learn commas.  Period.

What you want is aggregation.  I think:

```
SELECT Employee_Name
FROM EMPLOYEE_T ETT JOIN
     EMPLOYEE_SKILLS_T EST
     ON ETT.Employee_ID = EST.Employee_ID JOIN
     SKILL_T ST
     ON EST.Skill_ID = ST.Skill_ID 
GROUP BY Employee_Name
HAVING MIN(ST.Skill_Description) = MAX(ST.Skill_Description) AND
       MIN(ST.Skill_Description) = '12in Band Saw';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use aggregation:

```
select ett.employee_name
from employee_t as ett
inner join employee_skills_t as est on ett.employee_id = est.employee_id
inner join skill_t as st on est.skill_id = st.skill_id
group by ett.employee_name
having 
    min(st.skill_description) = max(st.skill_description)
    and min(st.skill_description) = '12in Band Saw'
```

The query joins the table, then groups by employee; the, the having clause ensures that there is only one distinct skill per group, and that it corresponds to the sought value.

Note that this query uses standard joins (with the `on` keywords) rather than implicit join (with commas in the `from` clause). As you are just starting to learn SQL, this is a habbit to permanently embrace.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: ah ah ah, you got me. At least I am consistent with my editing style!